# How to write progressing status into file

Tags: python

I want to print a progressing status. I use '\r' to implement it. Following is my code

```
#test.py
import sys

print("beg")
for i in range(10000):  
    sys.stdout.write("\r%% %d"%((i+1)*100.0/10000))
    sys.stdout.flush()
print("\nend")
```

It works in the terminal. But when I redirect the output, It can't work

```
python test.py > log.txt
```

**Right resolution from mhlester**

```
import sys

tty = sys.stdout.isatty()
print('beg')
if not tty:  
    position = sys.stdout.tell()                # get position
for i in range(10000):
    if tty:                                 # use falsetru's answer here
        sys.stdout.write('\r%% %d'%((i+1)*100.0/10000))# as you were before
    else:
        print('of')
        sys.stdout.seek(position)                  # or seek to position
        sys.stdout.write('%% %d'%((i+1)*100.0/10000))
    sys.stdout.flush()
print('\nend')
```

Comment: What if you just use `print` and redirect it ?
This code works here, was the file created ?

Comment: **print** will add the '\n' character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work for `stdout`, but it will work if you write to a file. Instead of `\r`, you need to `seek()` to the right position in the file. To find out the position you're at in the file, use `tell()`

```
    sys.stdout.write('beg')
    position = sys.stdout.tell()                # get position
    for i in range(10000):
        if tty:                                 # use falsetru's answer here
            print '\r',                         # as you were before
        else:
            out.seek(position)                  # or seek to position
        out.write('%% %d'%((i+1)*100.0/10000))
        out.flush()
    out.write('\nend')
```

Edited to work both ways

Comment: I print the information into the terminal most of the time. Just a little chance i need to redirect into a file

Answer (score 1):

Writing `\r` to the file behave different with writing it to the terminal.

It write byte 13 (0x0d) to the file instead of moving cursor.

You'd better check a stream is tty or not, then do different thing according to that.

```
>>> sys.stdout.isatty()
True
```

Comment: My system is also True of sys.stdout.isatty()

Comment: @Samuel, It returns `True` if `sys.stdout` is connected to the terminal. Otherwise (`sys.stdout` is a file), it returns `False`.

Comment: @Samuel, What is the expected content for the file?